# Django Home Page is not working. - NoReverseMatch at /en-us/

Tags: python, django, django-cms

http://django-path/admin is working

http://django-path throwing error

I have configured my django-cms in this ip address. I can access the admin part of the site and I cannot access the home page of the site. 
I am getting the following error,

```
NoReverseMatch at /en-us/

Reverse for 'cms_page_publish_page' with arguments '(6L, 'en-US')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 

1 pattern(s) tried: [u'en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/publish/$']
```

Comment: Sounds like your url is `en-us/admin/cms/page/6/en-US`, but the url pattern is `[a-z\-]+` for the second argument, which doesn't accept upper case letters, hence the error.

Comment: You are the rocker! It worked. I am a newbie. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you didn't enable the upper case characters in the pattern `u'en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/publish/$'`

Use `[a-zA-Z\\-]` instead of `[a-z\\-]` that you should be done

Also, I reccomend using named parameters like `(?P<language>[a-zA-Z\\-]+)`

Answer (score -1):

Change the regex pattern to allow for case-insensitive matches:

```
'(?i)en-us/admin/cms/page/([0-9]+)/([a-z\\-]+)/publish/$'
```

Note the (?i) embedded modifier at the beginning.

Python allows [perl-style](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) modifiers, so you can try those out.
Also please make use of named-parameters in your urls - makes it more digestible.

Comment: Downvoting without reason doesn't help anything.